# How to avoid 500 Internal Server Error if a JS session variable null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, long-polling

I created this script to read from various web sources. This script updates all notifications (mail, post, friends) and their own drop-down window's details and also two side update bars together. I used this script in my top manu.php page.

This script is working well for **login** user.

Now I pass a session id variable with JavaScript `var uid = '<? echo $session->id; ?>';` So when a user is not logged in, my browser console displays `500 Internal Server Error` because here the session has no ID so it passes uid= ''

How do I overcome this problem?

Here is my JavaScript script:

```
var uid = '<? echo $session->id; ?>';
    function addmailno(type, msg){
    //Do something for display mail/friend/post notification
    }

    function addmailup(type, msg){
    //Do something for display mail/post/friend drop-down.
    }

    function addside(type, msg){
    //Do something for display all friend/new post in side bar.
    }

    function waitFormailno(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "serverforupandside.php",
            cache: false,
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            data: "uid="+ uid,
            timeout:15000, 
            success: function(data){ 
                addmailno("MyDivClass", data);
                addmailup("MyDivClass", data);
                addside("MyDivId", data);
                setTimeout(waitFormailno, 15000);
            },
            error: function(){
                setTimeout(waitFormailno, 15000); 
            }
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitFormailno();
});
```

serverforupandside.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include_once("mysession.php");

while (true) {
if($_GET['uid']){
global $dbh;

//All php query is here one after one

//Output is here by data
$data = array();

$data['upmail'] = $upmail;
$data['upfollow'] = $upfollow;
$data['uppost'] = $uppost;
// etc all

    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        flush();
        mysqli_close($dbh);
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbh);
}
?>
```

Comment: are you getting error at `if($_GET['uid']){`? Try changing this to `if(!empty($_GET['uid'])){`

Comment: Also, where are you using `$_GET['uid']` in your code further?

Comment: I know this method only to get passing variable in php. Without `$_GET['uid']` how should better sir?

Comment: I am not clear with your statement "Without $_GET..". Were you able to identify what is causing 500 error? Why are you using infinite loop?`while (true) `?

Comment: I am trying to make my script like long polling. So used `while (true)`. In chrome browser console error display `500 error` if session not log in.

Comment: What sense is that `while (true)` loop supposed to make there?

Comment: Improved overall English to the best of my understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Javascript code** should be modified to:

```
function waitFormailno(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "serverforupandside.php",
            cache: false,
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            data: "uid="+ uid,
            timeout:15000, 
            success: function(data){ 
                addmailno("MyDivClass", data);
                addmailup("MyDivClass", data);
                addside("MyDivId", data);
            }
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(waitFormailno, 15000); // calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds)
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include_once("mysession.php");

if (!empty($_GET['uid'])) {
    global $dbh;

    //All php query is here one after one

    //Output is here by data
    $data = array();

    $data['upmail']   = $upmail;
    $data['upfollow'] = $upfollow;
    $data['uppost']   = $uppost;
    // etc all

    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }


}
```

Also, you should add validations before filling `$data` array.